# Topology intersection of neighbourhoods

Tags: general-topology

Hi in this theorem I am struggling understanding how I can be certain that V defined as the intersection of all the different neighbourhoods of different p's contains all p's. Would it not be possible that some of these neighbourhoods dont intersect and hence we louse one of the p's. Hence it would not be in V?

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: $p$ is fixed and each $V_q$ contains $p$, hence so does the intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $p \in K^c$ is any given point. Finite intersection of open sets of $V_{q_n}$ is still open.

Since each $V_{q_n}$ contains $p$, and $V_{q_n} \cap W_{q_n} = \emptyset$ for all $n$, we have $V \cap K = \emptyset$, i.e. $p \in V \subset K^c$. Thus, it proves that each given $p \in K^c$ is an interior point of $K^c$. So $K^c$ is open.

Comment: But how do I know that the intersection of v_qn contains all p. If one open subset does not intersect another then those p's would not be in V as v is the intersection.

Comment: @ALEXANDER Actually the logic here is the other way around: We firstly define $V_{q}$ to be an open set that contains $p$ (neighborhoods of $p$), and then we try to intersect finite number of them, which would result in an open set $V$ that contains $p$.

Comment: Ah, so V_q contains all neighborhoods of the p's and then we find a fint number of neighborhoods that contains p's hence the n in v_qn

Comment: Right, $\{V_q\}$ contains the neighborhoods of $p$'s. And then for each pair of $p$, $q$, we pick out $n$ element out of $\{V_q\}$, and name them as $V_{q_n}$ in pair with $W_{q_n}$.

Answer (score 0):

The $V_q$ are all **neighbourhoods of $p$** (despite their $q$ subscript: they are chosen to be disjoint with $W_q$, where $W_q$ is a neighbourhood of $q \in K$).

A finite intersection of neighbourhoods of a point $x$ is still a neighbourhood of that point $x$, basically because a finite intersection of open sets is still open.